# Delphi stream panel to file

Tags: delphi, stream

today I've a question about streaming a part of a form to a file.
In this example i use a Tmemo instead of file in order to see the stream.

here is my form:

[image]

The panel on the right top of the form has some controls, like label, edit and so on.
with the "Save panel" butto I save the panel on a TStream:

Here the code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  idx: Integer;
  MemStr: TStream;
begin
  MemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  PanelStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    for idx := 0 to pnlSource.ControlCount - 1 do begin
      MemStr.Position := 0;
      MemStr.WriteComponent(pnlSource.Controls[idx]);
      StreamConvert(MemStr);
    end;
    PanelStr.Position := 0;
    mmoStream.Lines.LoadFromStream(PanelStr);
  finally
    MemStr.Free;
  end;
end;
```

and here the StreamConvert:

```
{ Conversione stream in formato testo }
procedure TfrmMain.StreamConvert(aStream: TStream);
var
  ConvStream: TStream;
begin
  aStream.Position := 0;
  ConvStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ObjectBinaryToText(aStream, ConvStream);
    ConvStream.Position := 0;
    PanelStr.CopyFrom(ConvStream, ConvStream.Size);
    lblStreamSize.Caption := IntToStr(ConvStream.Size);
  finally
    ConvStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

PanelStr is a TStream object declared in private section of the form and create during form create.
This part works good and, as you can see in right part of the image the elements present on the form are register correctly.

Now my problem is to restore this element into the panel on the left bottom of the form.
I've tryed this routine:

```
{ Carica i controlli presenti nel pannello pnlSource in uno stream }
procedure TfrmMain.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  idx:  Integer;
  MemStr: TStream;
begin
  pnlSource.Free;
  MemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    PanelStr.Position := 0;
    ObjectTextToBinary(PanelStr, MemStr);
    MemStr.Position := 0;
    MemStr.ReadComponent(pnlTarget);
  finally
    MemStr.Free;
  end;
end;
```

but it doesn't work and in the following picture you can see the result:

[image]

What is wrong in my routine, and How can I read all the element present in the stream and not only the first?

Can someone help me in this headache?

Comment: As far as I can see, the list you have is the list of components in the original panel, but you are trying to read the properties of the target panel. The properties are not there, because the target panel is not defined in your source. What you would need to do is read the properties of the target panel and put them as a wrapper around the properties of the embedded components that you read, i.e. placing the data shown in the right panel just before the end statement of what you read from the destination panel, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are currently running effectively transforms the source panel to a label. That's because the first object streamed is a label and the code is reading only one component. IOW, when the reader reaches the first `end`, reading is complete since there are no *sub* controls in the stream.

So, first of all, you have to write the panel - and only the panel. The panel is the one that is supposed to stream it's children. To have it to do so, it must own it's controls.

```
var
  idx: Integer;
  MemStr: TStream;
begin
  MemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  PanelStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // transfer ownership of controls to the panel
    for idx := 0 to pnlSource.ControlCount - 1 do
      pnlSource.InsertComponent(pnlSource.Controls[idx]);
    // write the panel
    MemStr.WriteComponent(pnlSource);

    StreamConvert(MemStr);
    PanelStr.Position := 0;
    mmoStream.Lines.LoadFromStream(PanelStr);
  finally
    MemStr.Free;
  end;
```

This produces an output to the memo like this:

```
object pnlSource: TPanel
  Left = 8
  Top = 8
  Width = 201
  Height = 265
  Caption = 'pnlSource'
  TabOrder = 0
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 48
    Top = 208
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    ...
```

Note the indentation of the label definition and the missing 'end' of the owning panel (it's at the end).

You will need to register classes for the streamer to be able to find them when loading:

```
var
  idx:  Integer;
  MemStr: TStream;
begin
  pnlSource.Free;

  RegisterClasses([TLabel, TEdit, TCheckBox, TRadioButton]);

  MemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    PanelStr.Position := 0;
    ObjectTextToBinary(PanelStr, MemStr);
    MemStr.Position := 0;
    MemStr.ReadComponent(pnlTarget);
  finally
    MemStr.Free;
  end;
```

Registration can be of course moved to elsewhere, like form creation or unit initialization.

You can also transfer ownership of the controls back to the form if it's required, like in the saving code.

Comment: Just to clarify your first line. It doesn't change the TPanel into a TLabel. It is still a TPanel. But all ReadComponent does in the original code it read the first object (TLabel), ignores what type it is (the documentation states that) and attempts to apply the properties of Label1 to Panel2. As it happens TLabel and TPanel have the same published properties, which is why the original code does not raise an exception and the panel moves to the top left as shown, looking a bit like the original Label1.

Answer (score 0):

As I put in my comments, you need to surround your data with Panel2 information. You also need to register each control type you are saving and restoring.

This means that only the load procedure needs to change - like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iTemp, iTemp2 : TStringList;
  MemStr: TStream;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // first read the destination panel an put it into a string list
  pnlSource.Free;
  iTemp := TStringList.Create;
  iTemp2 := TStringList.Create;
  iTemp.Duplicates := TDuplicates.dupAccept;
  iTemp2.Duplicates := TDuplicates.dupAccept;
  MemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    PanelStr.Position := 0;
    iTemp2.LoadFromStream( PanelStr ); // our original source
    PanelStr.Size := 0;
    MemStr.Position := 0;
    MemStr.WriteComponent(pnlTarget);
    StreamConvert(MemStr);
    // PanelStr now has our destination poanel.
    PanelStr.Position := 0;
    iTemp.LoadFromStream( PanelStr );
    for i := 0 to iTemp2.Count - 1 do
    begin
      iTemp.Insert( ITemp.Count - 1, iTemp2[ i ]);
    end;
    PanelStr.Size := 0;
    iTemp.SaveToStream( PanelStr );
    PanelStr.Position := 0;
    mmoStream.Lines.LoadFromStream(PanelStr);
    MemStr.Size := 0;
    PanelStr.Position := 0;
    ObjectTextToBinary( PanelStr, MemStr);
    MemStr.Position := 0;
    RegisterClass( TLabel );
    RegisterClass( TPanel );
    RegisterClass( TEdit );
    RegisterClass( TCheckBox );
    RegisterClass( TRadioButton );
    MemStr.ReadComponent( pnlTarget );

  finally
    iTemp.Free;
    iTemp2.Free;
    MemStr.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As commented in the previous answer, registration can be put somewhere else.

Unlike the previous answer, you do not need to change the ownership of the controls first. (That is just a comment - not a criticism). This is just an implementation of my comment.

My naming conventions are different to yours. I have tried to use the same names, but forgive me if I have missed any.

Comment: Naming is fine, I could run it with paste only :). Anyway, I think it's worth noting that you're transferring ownership at a different stage and with a different manner: by modifying the stream manually. So, it's not that ownership of controls can stay with the form, but rather you don't have to alter it *first*. Like you, this is not a criticism, just wanted to note it.

Comment: Nice Sertac! Only one question: after the pnlSource is loaded into the pnlTarget this last one become pnlSource; is that right?

Comment: @Eros using Sertacs solution yes (unless you rename it first). Using my solution, No, it stays as pnlTarget.

Comment: Ok DSM, I've tryed Sertac's solution now I try your.