# How to make “serialize” and “unserialize” an array in delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-7

I need to do “serialize” and “unserialize” on delphi, like on php, so that the resulting array is then stored in the site database. Those. I need to get something like this kind.

> a:10:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj1";i:1;i:383;i:2;i:339;}i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj2";i:1;i:339;i:2;i:18;}i:2;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj3";i:1;i:386;i:2;i:98;}i:3;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj4";i:1;i:428;i:2;i:286;}i:4;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj5";i:1;i:54;i:2;i:47;}i:5;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj6";i:1;i:328;i:2;i:27;}i:6;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj7";i:1;i:332;i:2;i:371;}i:7;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj8";i:1;i:42;i:2;i:187;}i:8;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Obj9";i:1;i:314;i:2;i:68;}i:9;a:3:{i:0;s:5:"Obj10";i:1;i:124;i:2;i:120;}}

Here is my code adding an object in delphi:

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, Contnrs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
 TRect = class 
  private
   p:TPoint;
   width, height: Integer;
   color : TColor;
   str:String;
  public
    constructor Create(APt:TPoint;w1, h1: Integer; _Color:TColor;str1:String);
    Procedure Draw(Cs:TCanvas;x:Integer;y:Integer); 
  end;
   TRectList=class(TObjectList)
  private
    function GetItems(index:integer):TRect;
    procedure SetItems(index:integer; Value:TRect);
  public
    property Items[index:integer]: TRect read GetItems write SetItems; default;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ImPic : TBitmap;
  RectList: TRectList;
  rect : TRect;
  start : TPoint;
  ObjId:Integer;


implementation
{$R *.dfm}
constructor TRect.Create(APt:TPoint; w1, h1: Integer; _Color: TColor;str1:String);
begin
  p:=APt;
  width := w1;
  height := h1;
  color := _Color;
  str:=str1;

end;

procedure TRect.Draw(Cs:TCanvas; x, y: Integer);
begin
  Cs.Brush.Color:=color;
  Cs.Rectangle(p.X,p.Y,p.X+width,p.Y+height);
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i,x,y:Integer;
begin
x := Random(500);
y := Random(400);
ObjId := ObjId+1;

 start := Point(x, y);
 rect := TRect.Create(start,20,20,clBlue,'Obj'+IntToStr(ObjId));
 RectList.Add(rect);
 Memo1.Lines.Clear;
 Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
 Image1.Canvas.FillRect(Image1.ClientRect);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('[');
 for i := 0 to RectList.Count-1 do
 begin
   RectList[i].Draw(Image1.Canvas,RectList[i].p.X,RectList[i].p.Y);
   Memo1.Lines.Add('["'+RectList[i].str+'",'+IntToStr(RectList[i].p.X)+','+IntToStr(RectList[i].p.Y)+'],');
 end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(']');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
RectList := TRectList.Create(true);
randomize();
with Image1.Canvas do
begin
   brush.Color:=clSilver;
   Rectangle(0,0,width,height);
end;
end;
function TRectList.GetItems(index: integer):TRect;
begin
   Result := inherited Items[index] as TRect;
end;

procedure TRectList.SetItems(index: integer; Value: TRect);
begin
   inherited Items[index] := Value;
end;

end.
```

An array is generated in “memo”. Example in the picture:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0JBJ.jpg)
Then you can add this array to the php file, apply serialize, and you get the array that is shown at the top of the post. Php code:

```
$array = [
["Obj1",383,339],
["Obj2",339,18],
["Obj3",386,98],
["Obj4",428,286],
["Obj5",54,47],
["Obj6",328,27],
["Obj7",332,371],
["Obj8",42,187],
["Obj9",314,68],
["Obj10",124,120],
]
;
$string = serialize( $array );
echo $string."<br>";
$array = unserialize($string);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";  
?>
```

How to do the same thing on delphi “serialize” and “unserialize”, for subsequent storage in the mysql database on the site?

Comment: Choose a JSON library, and then use it

Comment: If you want to have your specialized format you have to write the code that does what you want. Otherwise you can getaway with the component streaming system. Search for WriteComponent/ReadComponent and friends. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021756/delphi-stream-panel-to-file

Comment: Where can I get a working JSON library for Delphi 7?

Comment: I'd start with websearch

Comment: This library https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject ?